# Realm errors when submiting to App Store

Tags: swift, realm

I'm working on cocos2d swift project made in spritebuilder and included realm as local database.

At first when I wanted to submit to I got [image: error itms 90035 invalid signature], to fix that one I had to delete strip-frameworks.sh from my project, but with that also came new [image: errors], so any help would be very nice, if someone already had these problems.

Thank you for any advice

Comment: What version of Realm are you using? I believe we've fixed this in our latest releases (0.93.2).

Comment: 9.92.3 for objective-c, ill try to update and let you know

Answer (score 1):

This is fixed in Realm 0.93.2 :)